# In mongodb how can i delete a validationed collection document field/record

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to delete a validationed collection document field /record by using the followng query but i am not getting actual output:

```
db.work.update( {}, {$unset:{Name:'abcd'}}, false,true)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'validationed' ? Also, what are you expecting as output? Did you try to query your documents to see if any document still had a `Name` property? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your query is correct, you should check your documents in the collection if there is a document which contains a field "Name". If there is, all the documents should have been updated by this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use `{Name:'abcd'}` as search criteria for un setting the Name value then your query should be: `db.work.update({Name:'abcd'},{$unset:{Name:true}},false,true)`.

What was the `nModified` value for the WriteResult ?